# How do I update scope from file-upload k-select event?

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, kendo-ui

When I read https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/AngularJS/introduction , it seems to suggest that for any event defined in the API for, I can use `k-on-` prefix instead of the `k-` prefix to set the event in such a way that it runs inside of the digest loop:

> Setting Handlers through k-on Attribute
>
> You can also specify event handlers by using attributes. They require the `k-on-` prefix.
>
> ```
> <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
>    <input kendo-date-picker k-on-change="onDateSelected(kendoEvent)" />
>    <p ng-show="selected">A month was picked</p>
>  </div>
> ```

…

> The `kendoEvent` variable is defined in a scope and you have to pass it to the event handler. If you are using the `k-on-` attributes, you do not need to call `$digest()` on the scope because your bindings take care of it.

However, when I try to do this with `file-upload`’s `select` event, my handler never runs:

```
<input name="files"
  type="file"
  kendo-upload
  k-async="{ saveUrl: 'save', removeUrl: 'remove', autoUpload: true }"
  k-on-select="onSelect"
  />
```

My handler does run if I pass it as `k-select` instead, but then sometimes the changes I make to `$scope` don’t result in my screen being updated.

Am I reading the Kendo documentation correctly? How do I work around this issue?

Comment: When you use `k-on-select` do you need to include the parens? i.e. `k-on-select="onSelect()"`

Comment: @Lex Thanks, that’s it! I guess that’s the AngularJS convention now that I realize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `k-on-select` attribute does, in fact, work. However, `k-on-select` will use [`Scope#$eval`](https://devdocs.io/angularjs~1.3/api/ng/type/$rootscope.scope#$eval) and execute it as an expression. This is the AngularJS convention for events. Since I passed an expression which resolves to a function, nothing happened each time my `k-on-select` was evaluated.

To call a function in an expression, you have to use the function invocation syntax `«function»()`. In kendo’s AngularJS support, it passes event information in a variable called `kendoEvent` (whereas events generated in AngularJS pass that information in a variable called `$event`). My corrected code looks like this:

```
<input name="files"
  type="file"
  kendo-upload
  k-async="{ saveUrl: 'save', removeUrl: 'remove', autoUpload: true }"
  k-on-select="onSelect(kendoEvent)"
  />
```

*Thanks to [Lex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548997) who pointed this out in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/95071026)!*